# Are RAID disks really universally unsupported for VMWare converter

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, physical-to-virtual, vmware-converter

I am preparing to virtualize our DC, which runs on SBS2008. We have eliminated the >2TB GPT disks and prepared some disk level backups with Acronis to use for the conversion. I plan to use the VMWare converter, rather than the acronis VM recovery; I have been reading through it's documentation though, and found something surprising: RAID drives are listed as unsupported source volumes for all formats. [http://www.vmware.com/pdf/convsa_50_guide.pdf (page 16)]

This isn't further explained, and a text search for RAID finds no other occurrence of it in the document. If this is true I essentially have to explain to my boss we flat out can't o something I had assumed would be, if not simple, at least possible. Does anyone have any experience with this? Perhaps this is only in the case of 'dumb' controllers?

If it really is the case, is there a better method I could investigate which does support RAID?

Comment: Thats for volume based cloning.  Do you have a software raid volume?

Comment: nope, it's a hardware raid controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they're talking about are RAIDed *Windows* volumes (i.e. Dynamic Disks that also have a windows RAID 10 or RAID5 array ontop of them). So if you're using Windows RAID then you're basically out.

However, if your volume is running on a hardware RAID ("real" RAID or "fake" RAID) and you're doing an online conversion, you should be fine.

Comment: How about if its a conversion from Acronis Backup (we have a real raid controller, so no windows RAID), as opposed to a live conversion?

Comment: if you are using software raid- simply break the mirror or striped volume.

Comment: Nope, hardware (LSI MegaRAID FWIW)

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly - I can't answer that because I've never done a conversion from a backup.

Comment: Oh well, I suppose I'll find out. Thanks for clearing up the RAID thing!